# At a center of Gödel's universe

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, reference-frames, observers

A few quick questions clarifying a picture about Gödel's universe, they bug me badly!
[image: Taken from]

Taken from [here](http://mekurt.blogspot.se/search/label/G%C3%B6del).
So Gödel's universe is made out of dust particles. All of them have angular velocity.
Do this universe has a center everything rotates around?

Let's say I am an observing dust particle. Do I have to do something particular to see everything rotating around me (getting at the center of picture)?

Comment: Presumably you mean 'center' in the title?

Comment: Is there a mechanism that couples spin to orbital angular momentum? If there isn't, there is no center that one could speak of.

Comment: @CuriousOne As far as I recall, there is no momentum there.  So it is just that  a bunch of particles with angular velocity looking property?

Comment: My point is that it's not a sufficiently defined system.

Comment: Here is a paper on this https://arxiv.org/ftp/gr-qc/papers/0106/0106070.pdf

Comment: It doesn't have a centre, it is spatially homogeneous.

Comment: @MBN If I am a dust particle do I see everything rotating around me and dust particle next to me sees universe rotating around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Gödel universe is homogeneous and every observer anywhere in the universe observes the universe to be rotating around them. So a Gödel universe has no centre.